# C++ static only methods?

Tags: c++, oop

I was wondering if it is possible to create class methods that are only available statically.

Given a simple Vector3 class:

```
class Vector3
{
public:
    float X;
    float Y;
    float Z;

    Vector3(): X(0), Y(0), Z(0) {}
    Vector3(float x, float y, float z): X(x), Y(y), Z(z) {}
    static Vector3 CrossProduct(const Vector3& rhs, const Vector3& lhs);
};

Vector3 Vector3::CrossProduct(const Vector3& rhs, const Vector3& lhs)
{ 
    Vector3 crossProductVec;

    crossProductVec.X = rhs.Y * lhs.Z - rhs.Z * lhs.Y;
    crossProductVec.Y = rhs.Z * lhs.X - rhs.X * lhs.Z;
    crossProductVec.Z = rhs.X * lhs.Y - rhs.Y * lhs.X;

    return crossProductVec;
}
```

and I can use it like this:

```
Vector3 vec1(0,1,0);
Vector3 vec2(1,0,0);

Vector3::CrossProduct(vec1, vec2); //this should work, and does. 
                                   //Static CrossProduct method.

vec1.CrossProduct(vec1, vec2);     //this shouldn't work, but it does.  
                                   //I don't want the CrossProduct  
                                   //instance method to be available
```

I would like `CrossProduct` to only be available statically. Is this possible?

I understand that the code above will not achieve what I want, I wish to know what changes could be made to achieve what I want.

**Edit:**

The CrossProduct() does not necessarily have to be part of the class, but I am hoping for it to appear as `Vector3::CrossProduct()`. I'm open to all suggestions to achieve the required result. After that a decision of whether it's a good idea or not can be worked out.

Comment: Aesthetics and curiousity.

Comment: @Appleshell what compiler and flags are you using to get a warning from that?

Comment: When you say it doesn't necessarily have to be part of the class, would something like `Vector3 CrossProduct(const Vector3& rhs, const Vector3& lhs)...` suffice?

Comment: @jkyako Hmmm... I was intending for the `Vector3::` to be prepended. I have also attempted taking `CrossProduct()` out of the class and putting it into a namespace but of course, there seemed to be conflicts between the class and namespace names.

Comment: Oh, guess I misunderstood your wording in the Edit text.

Comment: @jkyako Ok, I've clarified it a little more now.

Comment: @RyanHaining I just checked it, you'r right, it doesn't. It's a Java warning that I thought of.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to suppress the `vec1.` syntax. The standard section `[over.match.funcs]` says that static functions are always considered to have the implicit object parameter, for the purposes of overload resolution. I don't see any solid reason why this must be the case, however supporting your syntax would make compiler writers' life more difficult, for no practical gain really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think there is a way of doing what you want but you could ([and possibly should](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197)) make the function a non-member non-friend function in a namespace, preferably the same namespace as `Vector3`. Something like:

```
namespace Math {
   Vector3 CrossProduct(const Vector3& rhs, const Vector3& lhs);
}
```

Then you can use it with:

```
Math::CrossProduct(vec1, vec2);
```

Note that if `Vector3` is in the same namespace as CrossProduct, you can use [argument dependent lookup (ADL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) and omit the `Math::` if you wish.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried that putting `CrossProduct()` in a namespace before but I get a "redefinition of 'Vector3' as different kind of symbol" errors amongst many others. Should this work?

Answer (score 1):

It is only available statically in the sense that it can only modify local and static members of the class. `vect.CrossProduct()` will be compiled as `Vector3::CrossProduct()`.

You seem adamant about not having a member function and I don't know why. Instead of not having a member function, how about having a `const` member function that cannot modify itself:

```
class Vector3f
{
    //...
    public:
        Vector3f CrossProduct( const Vector3f& v ) const;
};

Vector3f Vector3f CrossProduct( const Vector3f& v ) const
{
    //...
}

v1.CrossProduct( v1, v2 ); // compiler error: parameter lists don't match
```

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks for your answer. But is there any way to force the `Vector3::CrossProduct()` syntax to be required? ie. make it throw errors otherwise. The CrossProduct() does not necessarily have to be part of the class. I'm open to all suggestions to achieve the required result. After that a decision of whether it's a good idea or not can be worked out.

Comment: @Jace, editted. Can you describe why you don't want this syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Under your declarations, these are the same

```
Vector3::CrossProduct(vec1, vec2); 

vec1.CrossProduct(vec1, vec2);
```

Comment: Yes I realise that. I was wondering what changes I would be able to make so that they aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `Crossproduct` simply just have to be declared as a seperate function outside the class definition.

> Vector3 CrossProduct(const Vector3& lhs, const Vector3& rhs);

or you instead of making it static, just declare it as a regular member function like

> Vector3 CrossProduct(const Vector3& rhs);

which uses `*this` for the LHS.

I would suggest that you do both, like this;

```
class vector3 {
  ....
  Vector3 CrossProduct(const Vector3& rhs);
};
inline Vector3 CrossProduct(const Vector3& lhs, const Vector3& rhs) { return lhs.Crossproduct(rhs); }
```